# How to scale an object based off of Text size and length in Unreal?

Tags: unreal-engine4

This maybe an easy question maybe not. Essentially, I am creating a VR application and I am also making a 3D UI system for it. I have the basics of creating a 3D button and clicking it done already. What I want to do now is scale my button in order to fit my custom text inside of it. Is there a way to automatically scale the object based off of the size of another? I'll attach some pictures to maybe describe the problem and what I want to accomplish.

Currently,

[image]

What I want to happen in something like the ConstructionScript:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/BlueprintAPI/Widget/GetDesiredSize/index.html

Try something like this , you call if from text variable, it return struct with X and Y float , hope it may give u starting point.

Edit :
You can get Text render TextlocalSize or TextworldSize .

Comment: I'm using a TextRenderer component on an actor BP not a widget.

Comment: Edited the answer, I wasn't focus much